# Full path not working with find

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find

I use this command to delete all files apart from .htaccess in current directory.

```
find . -depth -name .htaccess -prune -o -delete
```

I want to make a shortcut so I am trying to make it work with fully qualified path like

```
find /path/to/my/cache/dir/ -depth -name .htaccess -prune -o -delete
```

but it always says directory not found even though path is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Go into the directory that has the actual files in question, type "pwd" and then use the returned string in your find command.

Comment: This combination of `-depth` and `-prune` is not going to work anyway

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if the last segment of the full path (here: `dir`) is a symbolic link, then find takes it as a link file, but doesn’t follow the link.

```
cd /path/to/my/cache
ls
```

If you get something like

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root       21 Mai 26  2020 dir -> /media/share/cache/
```

use that path in your find command, and it works.